# Convert string of byte array back to original string in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a plain text string that I'm converting to a byte array and then to a string and storing in a database.

Here is how I'm doing it:

```
    Dim b As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello")
    Dim s As String = BitConverter.ToString(b).Replace("-", "")
```

Afterwards I store the value of s (which is "48656C6C6F") into a database.

Later on, I want to retrieve this value from the database and convert it back to "Hello". How would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call the following function with your hex string and get "Hello" returned to you. Note that the function doesn't validate the input, you would need to add validation unless you can be sure the input is valid.

```
Private Function HexToString(ByVal hex As String) As String
    Dim result As String = ""
    For i As integer = 0 To hex.Length - 1 Step 2
        Dim num As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(hex.Substring(i, 2), 16)
        result &= Chr(num)
    Next
    Return result
End Function
```

James Thorpe points out in his comment that it would be more appropriate to use Encoding.UTF8.GetString to convert back to a string as that is the reverse of the method used to create the hex string in the first place. I agree, but as my original answer was already accepted, I hesitate to change it, so I am adding an alternative version. The note about validation of input being skipped still applies.

```
Private Function HexToString(ByVal hex As String) As String
    Dim bytes(hex.Length \ 2 - 1) As Byte 
    For i As Integer = 0 To hex.Length - 1 Step 2
        bytes(i \ 2) = Byte.Parse(hex.Substring(i, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)
    Next
    Return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes)
End Function
```

Comment: Consider using the [`ChrW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/613dxh46%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) function if you're going to go that route so you can support unicode.  Be aware that these functions are hangovers from VB6 though, and you'd be better off using [`Encoding.UTF8.GetString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/744y86tc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) since it's the "opposite" action of what was used to get the bytes in the first place.

Comment: @JamesThorpe: I agree and have added alternative code in my answer. Thank you.